# How can I integrate spring security with rest oauth2 services and spring social?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-social

I have an app (A) exposing REST services secured with oauth2. (spring security oauth2/spring-web)
I want to create a second app (B) (spring-boot or normal spring), from where I can login then call the REST services from A.

How can I configure security in app B so I can use both social login (facebook, twitter, google) and call REST services from app A? Is there an example using spring security/oauth/social integration?

I've found some examples but none sais how to integrate them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tries the [Spring oAuth2 tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) with FB and Google login? This also includes a local login. All code is available in git from the link in the right column of the tutorial.

Comment: I tried it before but it is not what I was looking for. I was looking for a easy solution and this helped me understand that I have to really understand how things work and not just "take that configuration" "put it there".
So I'll mark this as the answer :) Big like